How to build a double wall carbon nanotube with a Moiré pattern
I want to build a structure file for a double-wall carbon nanotube where the walls of the two tubes would be twisted at a special angle to have the Moiré pattern.
Could anyone please give me some suggestions on how to build such a structure through coding?
Is there any method to do so?
Thank you in advance.

You can try with ChiralTube: https://github.com/Chema-dac/chiraltube. Start with two layers of carbon where you can specify the twistting angle, and then use the tool I just mentioned to roll the structure into a tube.
